# Too many password attempts

Tags: lock-screens, password, locked-out

While I was out, someone attempted to guess my phone password. They couldn't guess it and now it displays the 'too many password attempts' screen, which needs to be unlocked with a google account. However, my google account is not working. I enter the username and password correctly, and have attempted to do so about 10 times. So why is it not unlocking? Do I need an internet connection to unlock it?

Answer (score 5):

You won't need an internet connection.

Also, when typing the username/email, make sure you have either @gmail.com or @googlemail.com at the end, depending on what it was when you added the account.

If you didn't add anything, the default for android <= 2.3 is @googlemail.com

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but how can it connect to the internet without being unlocked?

Comment: Sorry - typo error. It doesn't actually connect to the internet. It checks the entered details with the details entered on the device. It does however, connect to the internet sometimes to confirm the password.

Comment: No password with the @googlemail.com account?

Comment: Actually, the whole point of the question is to circumvent this password screen. If this is not possible, please say.

Comment: The only way would be to wipe it - recovery or otherwise. If you do not have recovery, it would be impossible.

Comment: OK, I guess I'll just enter random names and hope something works.

Comment: @liamwli is there a way to cancel this feature at all?? my kids are locking it daily and I'm using 2 step verification so I have to regenerate passwords over and over.

Comment: I'm afraid not, unless you completely edit the android system (but then you would be making a custom rom). You would have to disable the lock - or do what I do, and write you 2 step passwords down :)

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of this annoying "feature"!?

Comment: _"It checks the entered details with the details entered on the device."_ - it caches the credentials locally? Everything I read on the internet begs to differ, could you link to the source of this info if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Go Here and sign in with your google account:  https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager

Lock it from the WEB and then use that password to open you device - I just did it on my son's and we saved everything!   I thought I was going to have to wipe it, but didn't.  Good luck